# Shadowing/darkening filter on an image

Tags: image, photoshop, photo

I'm looking for an easy way to apply shadowing/darkening filter to a photo. Essentially, the filter just needs to darken colors on the photo. What can I use?

Comment: Add a `brightness/contrast` layer and move the brightness slider left maybe. Or a `curves` layer and pull the middle downwards. Or a `levels` layer and slide the middle slider across.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different action photoshop. You'll find a lot to download and you can apply it until you're happy with final result